# Showing that $|y^{1/k - 1}| = y^{1/k - 1}$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ odd

Tags: real-analysis

In my stochastic exercise sheet I encountered the expression $$|y^{1/k - 1}|$$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ odd. Since $k$ odd, we have $k = 2n + 1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we get $$\frac{1}{2n + 1} - 1 = \frac{2n}{2n + 1}$$ Hence the numerator is an even number and thus I suggest that $$|y^{1/k - 1}| = y^{1/k - 1}$$ However, I somehow never encountered the formal definition of a power of a negative base, and thus I am a bit confused how to do this properly. Is my result right? How do I formalize it?

Comment: This is context dependent.  Do you want $a^b$ to depend on how $b$ is represented?  If not, there's no general definition of $a^b$ when $a$ is negative.  E.g., which of the following do you buy?  $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$, $(-1)^{2/6}=1$.  You can reduce fractions first, and yours already is, but still, it depends on context: Which would be a useful and consistent definition of $a^b$ for the context you're using it in?  (If the exponent is irrational it's even worse.)  You're dealing with roots, and you can say you always take the positive one when one exists, as it does in your case.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks, of course. Fixed it.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think the definition that I take the positive root if it exists is usefull. I will adapt it here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented about the general need for context in how the exponents are defined.  That may be excessively careful in this case, as long as your context is one in which you are only interested in real outputs.  In that case, because $k$ is odd, $y^{1/k-1}$ always has exactly $1$ sensible definition as a real number when $y$ is real and nonzero, and with that definition it is indeed positive.  $$y^{1/k-1}=y^{(1-k)/k}=\sqrt[k]{y^{1-k}},$$ where $\sqrt[k]{x}$ is defined to be the positive real $k$th root of the positive number $x$, and this applies because the integer $1-k$ is even so $y^{1-k}$ (defined unambiguously) is positive.

---

(If $k$ were negative it would be $\sqrt[-k]{y^{k-1}}$. Alternatively, this is $\dfrac{\sqrt[k]{y}}{y}$ when $k>0$, $\dfrac{1}{y\sqrt[-k]{y}}$ when $k<0$. There are $|k|-1$ other possible values if complex numbers are allowed, but only the positive one is real, so all of the above compute the same thing.)